# Android back button

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm trying to make a back in the action bar on the top left but it keeps getting me null pointer exception and i don't know why here's my code

here's the class which displays the back screen

```
    ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    //for color
    bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#5c7afe")));


    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.company_info1);
     // get the action bar
    android.app.ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();


    // Enabling Back navigation on Action Bar icon
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

and here's my manifest file

```
      <activity android:name="com.example.hotlinesegypt.company_info"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.hotlinesegypt.Company" >
```

and here's my log cat

```
08-21 15:51:32.614: E/AndroidRuntime(16777): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-21 15:51:32.614: E/AndroidRuntime(16777): Process: mo.hot.hotlinak, PID: 16777
08-21 15:51:32.614: E/AndroidRuntime(16777): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{mo.hot.hotlinak/com.example.hotlinesegypt.Company}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-21 15:51:32.614: E/AndroidRuntime(16777):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
08-21 15:51:32.614: E/AndroidRuntime(16777):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
08-21 15:51:32.614: E/AndroidRuntime(16777):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
08-21 15:51:32.614: E/AndroidRuntime(16777):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
08-21 15:51:32.614: E/AndroidRuntime(16777):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-21 15:51:32.614: E/AndroidRuntime(16777):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
08-21 15:51:32.614: E/AndroidRuntime(16777):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
08-21 15:51:32.614: E/AndroidRuntime(16777):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-21 15:51:32.614: E/AndroidRuntime(16777):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-21 15:51:32.614: E/AndroidRuntime(16777):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
08-21 15:51:32.614: E/AndroidRuntime(16777):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
08-21 15:51:32.614: E/AndroidRuntime(16777):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-21 15:51:32.614: E/AndroidRuntime(16777): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-21 15:51:32.614: E/AndroidRuntime(16777):    at com.example.hotlinesegypt.Company.onCreate(Company.java:46)
08-21 15:51:32.614: E/AndroidRuntime(16777):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5426)
08-21 15:51:32.614: E/AndroidRuntime(16777):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
08-21 15:51:32.614: E/AndroidRuntime(16777):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
```

Comment: whats on Company.java:46 ?

Comment: indicate line `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 08-21 15:51:32.614: E/AndroidRuntime(16777): at com.example.hotlinesegypt.Company.onCreate(Company.java:46) 08-21 `

Comment: extends ur activity with ActionBarActivity also add this setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you've just got your variable names confused on this line you create your `ActionBar` variable called bar

```
ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
```

Then you refer to it as `actionBar` here:

```
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Change this line to be:

```
bar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

That looks like what it is but you need to check line 46 of Company to see if it what I have suggested